# Polynomial such that $P(\sin x)=a\cos x+b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Given four real numbers $a,b,\alpha,\beta$ with $ a\ne0, \alpha<\beta$. Does there exist a real coefficient polynomial $P(x)$ such that

$$P(\sin x)=a\cos x+b$$

hold for all $x\in (\alpha,\beta)$?

I can but prove a special case: if $b=0$, $P(x)$ does not exist

Comment: Define $Q(x)=P(x)-b$, then you answered your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Evaluate at $0$ to get $P(0)=a+b$. Evaluate at $\pi$ to get $b-a=P(0)$. This gives $P(0)=b$. Then $Q=P-P(0)$ is polynomial with $Q(\sin x)=a\cos x$

Answer (score 0):

The sine function is not a polynomial function of the cosine function.  Isn't this the basic problem?